# Excel Formula - To find the blank, incorrect date and correct date format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Experts, I am struggling to create a formula for identifying incorrect, correct date format and blank cells. The formula i built is.

```
=if(AND(A2<>,""),datevalue(text(A2,"MMM/DD/YYYY"))),0)).
```

Cell with date format like 01/21/2023 are getting result as 0 but other than that such as 21/01/2023 which is incorrect date format as per my requirement is showing as '#values', same with blank cells. I want result either correct format as 0, incorrect format 1 and blank cell as 'no date' or 2 no.

Comment: What are you trying here `AND(A2<>,"")` ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need a formula to identify the date format in a particular cell. I pulled a data sheet which contains date in few of the columns. Those dates can be in any format such as dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy. For my project i need th3 format as mm/dd/yyyy. I need to identify which cell has dd/mm/yyyy format date or blank cells. The data is in large quantity hence cannot work manually on filtering rather use formula